# Using list names as names for sheets using XLConnect

Tags: r, xlconnect

As the title suggest, I would like to do the above. Example below:

```
library(stringr)
library(XLConnect)

df <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(1:10, function(i) rnorm(10))))
df.list <- rep(list(df), 10)
names(df.list) <- paste("DataFrame", str_pad(1:length(df.list), 2, pad = "0"), sep = "")

df.list.workbook <- loadWorkbook("df.list.workbook.xlsx", create = TRUE)
lapply(1:length(df.list), function(i) createSheet(df.list.workbook, name = names(df.list[i])))
lapply(df.list[1:length(df.list)], function(i) writeWorksheet(df.list.workbook, i, sheet = names(i)))
```

The last line is where it throws up an error:

```
Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..9)
```

To troubleshoot this, I tried:

```
lapply(df.list[1:length(df.list)], function(i) print(names(i)))
```

And realise that the names of the columns were being passed to the sheet variable. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: @James, that give me `Error in print(names(df.list)[i]) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in names(df.list)[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: Ah, I see. Would also need to change to: `lapply(seq_along(df.list), function(i) writeWorksheet(df.list.workbook, df.list[[i]], sheet = names(df.list)[i])`. Need to lapply over the index instead of the list.

Comment: Brilliant! Could you submit it as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `lapply` over the index instead of the list:

```
lapply(seq_along(df.list), function(i) writeWorksheet(df.list.workbook, df.list[[i]], sheet = names(df.list)[i]))
```

Answer (score 3):

XLConnect is vectorized in many places. In your case this holds for `createSheet` and `writeWorksheet`, so you can write:

```
df.list.workbook <- loadWorkbook("df.list.workbook.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(df.list.workbook, name = names(df.list))
writeWorksheet(df.list.workbook, data = df.list, sheet = names(df.list))
saveWorkbook(df.list.workbook)
```